# Ability to split word document(s) into based on section breaks or quickparts

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a template word document that is filled up by users. 
This word document contains text and tables that I wish to extract to sharepoint.

Is it possible to extract just the table in it and compare this extracted table with another extracted table from a different file (Also using the same template but with different fields).

Just want to know the feasibility of this concept

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the table to excel and then export excel to SharePoint list:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/copy-a-word-table-into-excel-b4f89ace-513c-4226-a167-ea3a9c307e43

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-an-excel-table-to-sharepoint-974544f9-94bc-4aa8-9159-97282d256dab

And for the compare part, i am not pretty sure about your requirement, please say a bit more about it.